# Wireless internet provider and a local wifi network?

Tags: network, wifi, internet

I live in a building that has wireless internet.  How do I use it while also having access to my wifi network, which connects my Mac to my other devices (Philips Hue, Belkin Wemo, streaming music from my Mac to my Apple TV, etc).

I'm using the latest version of macOS/OSX on a Mac Mini, plus an iPhone and an iPad.  I also own an Apple Airport Extreme, which I'm using to serve my local wifi network.  I also have a 1st gen Airport Express that I haven't used in ages, but it's old enough that the OSX Airport Utility app can't configure it (I think it's from 2006?).

UPDATE:  I answered my own question.  See answer below (tl;dr: I bought a new Airport Express & added it to my setup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I answered my own question as follows:

I bought an Apple Airport Express and set it up on my building's wifi. Then, I connected it by ethernet cable to my Airport Extreme's WAN port. My Airport Extreme is still functioning just as it always has, broadcasting my local wifi network. I've been testing this for over a week now and it's been flawless. Best of all, the current Airport Express model can be found on ebay for under $40 shipped.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect your Mac Mini to the building's wireless network, and then via Ethernet to your AirPort Extreme. Then setup Internet sharing from Wifi to Ethernet and you'll be able to have both internet from your wireless provider and a local wifi network for your IoT devices and streaming setup.

1. Connect the ethernet cable to the Mac
2. Launch “System Preferences” from the  Apple menu and click on “Sharing”
3. Click on “Internet Sharing” from the left menu
4. Select the pull-down menu next to “Share your connection from:” and choose “Wifi ” or "AirPort"
5. Alongside “To computers using:” check the box next to “Ethernet”
6. Click Ok

Then open Airport Utility and [configure your AirPort Extreme](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH5131?locale=en_US) unit as follows:

1. Open AirPort Utility, located in the Utilities folder in the Applications folder. Select the base station you want to set up, then click Edit.
2. Click Network, and then choose Off (Bridge Mode) from the Router Mode pop-up menu.

With NAT and DHCP turned off, the base station acts as a simple bridge between the wired and wireless computers on the network.

Only your Mac Mini should connect to your building wireless network; if any other device of yours connects to it you won't "see" it on your local network.

Comment: Interesting!  This works like a charm.  So, basically what this does is add whatever I've set up to share in my Mac's Preferences/Sharing to the local wifi network on my Airport Extreme...  correct?

Comment: It converts your Mac into a router that can assign DHCP addresses to a local network. Then your AirPort Extreme takes one of those addresses and on its turn does the same to create yet another network, this time with a wireless access point. You may have some trouble to reach your Mac Mini when connected to the AirPort Extreme network (I'm thinking on a printer connected to it for instance, and trying to print from one iOS device).

Comment: I can't help wondering if there's a better way to accomplish this.  Is there an Ethernet wifi gizmo I can buy to plug into my router?  Sometimes, this setup works.  Sometimes, it'll drop a device - usually Hue, which has a hub that must be connected to the router by ethernet cable.  Sometimes, my Mac can see Hue but my iPhone can't.  Other times, my iPhone can, but my Mac can't.  I've had Hue since 2013 and it's been flawless until now.  Also, some iPhone apps that connect to my Mac (BTT Remote, for example) aren't reliable anymore.

Comment: Ah, shoot.  It looks like this won't work.  My iPhone and iPad can connect to my Apple TV, but my Mac cannot, presumably because my Apple TV is on my wireless network, but my Mac is not.

Comment: I'll add configuration details

Comment: Using "Airport Ulitlity Launcher" from http://zcs.zyniker.org/airport-utility-v5-6-1/ and/or http://stickyworknotes.blogspot.ca/2016/01/apple-airport-utility-561-on-el-capitan.html you might be able to get the old Airport Express to act as the bridge between the building network and your appartment network instead of using the MacMini. Plug the old Airport Express into the Extreme's "WAN" port and plug the MacMini into the Airport Extreme "LAN" plug rather than the "WAN" plug. All your devices should connect on the "LAN" side, and all have access to the internet through the WAN connection.

Comment: Old AirPort Express units have only one port.

Comment: Added instructions to set the AirPort Extreme to bridge mode, so DHCP is be managed by your Mac Mini. You should be able to see all your devices on the local network.

Comment: Don't the new instructions drop my Philips Hue off my Airport Extreme even though it's connected by ethernet? Bridge mode turns off its DHCP reservation.

This does send internet from my Mac to all of my other devices, but it drops Hue off my network entirely.

Comment: Using the utility recommended above, I got my Airport Express working.  If I can figure out how to have it pick up my building's wifi (instead of using my Mac to pick up the building's wifi), I should be able to connect it (the Airport Express) to my Airport Extreme by ethernet cable, and thus, the Airport Express would be acting like a wifi modem, serving internet into my Airport Extreme exactly as my cable modem used to.

...but how?  How do I tell the Airport Express to pick up the building's wifi?

Comment: You can't share internet from the ethernet port of an AirPort Express when on client mode: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204371

Comment: This may help: https://www.amazon.com/NETGEAR-Universal-Ethernet-Adapter-WNCE2001/dp/B003KPBRRW; replace your Mac Mini with this or a similar wifi to ethernet bridge and connect the ethernet cable to your AirPort Extreme WAN port.

Comment: That Netgear adapter says it "Adds wireless capability to any Ethernet-enabled device" but I'm trying to do the exact opposite.  I'm trying to connect my building's wifi internet to my Airport Extreme router and serve it to the devices on my own wifi network.

Comment: Yeah, in practice the problem is that you want to use your airport wifi for your local network, so it is as if your AirPort Extreme didn't have wifi and you were trying to add wifi capabilities to it. Another option is to buy a WDS capable router, and build your network with that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I found a solution.  I bought a current gen Airport Express, which I'll set up in client mode (pretty much as j-beda described above, but the old Airport Express lacks this ability, so I had to pick up a more recent one).  The Airport Express will act as a bridge between my building's wifi and ethernet.  I'll connect the Airport Express to my Airport Extreme's WAN port, just as I would have done with a cable modem.  My Airport Extreme will stay as it has been.  It'll be my ethernet and wireless router, serving my wifi network.

Comment: Perfect, its exactly what the Netgear gizmo would have done.

Comment: You should add the relevant comments to your question and your solution as an answer and mark it as solved.